# How do I make a new top level menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a new Menu in the admin panel of Wordpress for my new plugin. Just like 'Tools', 'Users', 'Settings', I want a new item, 'My Plugin'.
I'm aware of the function `add_menu_page()`, but how do I use it?

What is the code for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For how-to on `add_menu_page()` follow this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus). For most of the wordpress function you can use [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org). Eg/

```
add_menu_page($page_title, $menu_title, $access_level, $file, $callback_function, $icon_url);
```

Comment: I figured that out...but thnx!!

Comment: What is the $file parameter that I don't find in codex?

Answer (score 0):

yes what Pragati Sureka said is true. it's the right way to do it. You just have to put it in functions.php in your theme file